# absolute maven pomderived entry added to classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have this extra relative source directory added to my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>../../my-framework/backend/src</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I must add a relative source path here, because this project and the framework project will be checked out by other developers. The relative paths in the workspace will be the same, but the absolute location of the workspace itself will be different for each developer.

This works perfectly for the command line. (E.g. "mvn compile" works perfectly.) However, if I open the very same project from Eclipse and select "Maven update" from the menu, then it overwrites my .classpath file and puts in an entry that is similar to this:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="Users/MyUserName/workspace/my-framework/backend/src">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

This is bad, because it uses a path that is relative to my C: drive on Windows. It will be totally useless for another developer who is using Linux.

I can easily remove this generated entry from the .classpath, but the Eclipse Maven plugin will always overwrite it. The result is that this file always gets overwritten, and commited into the git repo with various different paths. This is wrong.

How can I permanently relativize the paths in my .classpath file?

Note: if I don't add the .classpath file to the git repo, then the compilation phase fails, because the .classpath file also contains the build path, including the launching JRE container.

**UPDATE**: I have converted the framework code to a separate module and a separate maven artifact, as suggested by khmarbaise. I can compile the framework into a jar, and install it into my local repository:

```
mvn package
mvn install
```

The jar file indeed appears in my ~/.m2/repository directory. Then I removed the build helper plugin from the application, and added an dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.not_telling</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-framework</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

But if I try to compile the application with "mvn compile" then I get a "package not found com.not_telling.some_inner_thing" error message. I'm still missing a piece.

Comment: Simply that sounds really weird to me. Why not making a separate module of the framework and reuse it via dependencies? Makes things easier....

Comment: Okay, probably you are right, and I need to add a jar dependency instead of a java source directory. I wonder how will eclipse handle that. I'm investigating, will be back shortly.

Comment: Updated the question. Separating them into different modules is a better idea indeed, I just can't compile the application, because it does not see the packages in my-framework.

Comment: Maybe we should close this question, creating a separate module is the right way to do it.

Comment: If it does not see the package you haven't defined a dependency to the module/project...