# Locally installed jar not seen by maven

Tags: java, maven

I have source code for a framework, let's call it `my-framework`. It provides various packages, including `com.not_telling.framework.db`.

I have a pom.xml file for this framework:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.not_telling</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-famework</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-framework Maven Library</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <!-- more things here... -->
</project>
```

I can compile this and install it to my local repository cache, using this command:

```
mvn install
```

End of the install log:

```
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\MyUserName\my-framework\backend\target\my-framework.jar to C:\Users\MyUserName\.m2\repository\com\not_telling\my-famework\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\my-famework-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\MyUserName\my-framework\backend\pom.xml to C:\Users\MyUserName\.m2\repository\com\not_telling\my-famework\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\my-famework-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I have another project, that tries to use this as a dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.not_telling</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-famework</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

The compilation phase of this project fails with this message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-project: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/MyUserName/workspace/my-project/backend/src/main/java/com/not_telling/some_example.java:[13,17] package com.not_telling.framework.db does not exist
```

Why is  that? Maybe because the jar is in the repository cache, but not in a local repository?

This question is a follow up of [absolute maven pomderived entry added to classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870724/absolute-maven-pomderived-entry-added-to-classpath) - I realized that instead of doing magic with relative source directory references, I need to make a separate module, but I'm facing this problem.

Comment: I'm not a Maven expert, but can you check your `.m2` folder and see if you can find something under the path `com/not_telling/framework` ?  If you don't see anything there, it could explain your observations.

Comment: In you source code `C:/Users/MyUserName/workspace/my-project/backend/src/main/java/com/not_telling/some_example.java:[13,17] package com.not_telling.framework.db does not exist` the given package in that file does not exist. You should check if this is the package which is really required or if the name is wrong etc.

Comment: `C:/Users/MyUserName/.m2/repository/com/not_telling` does exist. It contains a `maven-metadata-local.xml` file and a `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` directory with the jar inside. @khmarbaise - the package does exist, if I open both the framework and the application project from eclipse, then I can compile both. But I cannot compile the application with maven.

Comment: Have you checked cause the error message states different...

Comment: Maybe you accidentally put your `<dependency>` into `<dependencyManagement>` instead of `<dependencies>`? If Maven couldn't find a dependency, the error would be different - it wouldn't even get to `compile` phase.

Comment: Can you unzip the jar in m2? Is everything there?

Comment: There are no .class files in the jar. Just the pom.xml and pom.properties.

Comment: After moving source files under src/main/java, the class files appeared in the framework jar. But the application still cannot be compiled, with the same error message "package com.not_telling.framework.db does not exist". Additionally, eclipse went wrong and it also cannot compile with this error message: The declared package "com.not_telling.framework.db" does not match the expected package "main.java.com.not_telling.framework.db"

Answer (score 0):

It was bleeding from numerous wounds. These needed to be fixed:

- move source files from under src/ to under src/main/java, in both the framework and the application project
- change the group and the artifact id to match the package name E.g. for a package that is named "com.not_telling.framework" I had to use groupId=com.not_telling and name=framework.
- The dependency scope was wrong in the application's pom file. I had to remove test

Now it works from command line I can do "mvn install" for the framework, and then "mvn package" for the applications.

The only problem left is that the application cannot be compiled from eclipse, I had to remove all linked source folders / build paths in the application project to the framework.